# Qual o conceito por trás da propriedade IFilter.AllowMultiple?

Tags: c#, autenticação

Ao estudar a funcionalidade dos filtros da "**Web API Pipeline .NET Faramework**", me deparei com a propriedade "**AllowMultiple**", trazida por herança da classe abstrata "**IFilter**".

A documentação da Microsoft informa que é uma propriedade booleana que
***"obtém ou define um valor indicando se mais de uma instância do atributo indicado pode ser especificada para um único elemento do programa".***

Contudo, ou não entendi o conceito, ou não entendi o uso. Mesmo se eu definir o valor desta propriedade como verdadeiro (true), não posso usar mais de uma instância do filtro em um mesmo elemento do programa.

Segue abaixo a implementação do código do meu filtro:

```
    public class BasicAuthenticationFilter : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{    
    public bool AllowMultiple { get { return true; } }

    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var authorization = context.Request.Headers.Authorization;
        if (authorization != null &&
            string.Equals(authorization.Scheme, "Basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization.Parameter))
        {
            if (ExtractUserNameAndPassword(authorization.Parameter, out string userName, out string password) &&
                userName == "userName" && password == "123qwe")
            {
                var identity = new GenericIdentity(userName, "Basic");
                context.Principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
            }
            else
            {
                context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid username or password", context.Request);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Missing auth", context.Request);
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var host = context.Request.RequestUri.DnsSafeHost;
        context.Result = new AddChallengeOnUnauthorizedResult(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "realm=\"" + host + "\""), context.Result);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public class AddChallengeOnUnauthorizedResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        private readonly AuthenticationHeaderValue _challenge;
        private readonly IHttpActionResult _innerResult;

        public AddChallengeOnUnauthorizedResult(AuthenticationHeaderValue challenge, IHttpActionResult innerResult)
        {
            _challenge = challenge;
            _innerResult = innerResult;
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var response = await _innerResult.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized && response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.All(h => h.Scheme != _challenge.Scheme))
                response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(_challenge);
            return response;
        }
    }

    private bool ExtractUserNameAndPassword(string authorizationParameter, out string userName, out string password)
    {
        userName = null;
        password = null;
        byte[] credentialBytes;
        try
        {
            credentialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(authorizationParameter);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        var decodedCredentials = encoding.GetString(credentialBytes);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(decodedCredentials))
        {
            return false;
        }

        int colonIndex = decodedCredentials.IndexOf(':');
        if (colonIndex == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        userName = decodedCredentials.Substring(0, colonIndex);
        password = decodedCredentials.Substring(colonIndex + 1);
        return true;
    }

    public class AuthenticationFailureResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public AuthenticationFailureResult(string reasonPhrase, HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            ReasonPhrase = reasonPhrase;
            Request = request;
        }

        public string ReasonPhrase { get; private set; }

        public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; private set; }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(Execute());
        }

        private HttpResponseMessage Execute()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            response.RequestMessage = Request;
            response.ReasonPhrase = ReasonPhrase;
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

A utilização desta classe como atributo mais de uma vez em um único elemento do programa gera erro de compilação (*Duplicate "BasicAuthenticationFilter" atributte*) na segunda citação do atributo :

```
[BasicAuthenticationFilter]
[BasicAuthenticationFilter]

public class StudioGhibliController : ApiController
{
    public HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }
    public string ApiUrlPrefix { get; set; }
    public HttpResponseMessage Response { get; set; }
    public StudioGhibliController()
    {...
```

Qual seria então o conceito e o uso correto desta propriedade? Para que realmente ela serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vamos simplificar um pouco as coisas. Acho que através de um exemplo as coisas ficam mais fáceis.
Criei um projetinho de exemplo onde você poderá testar o conceito. Pra adiantar vamos lá:
Criei um projeto asp.net web api e nele criei uma classe onde implementei a interface IACtionFilter.

```
 public class MyFilter : IActionFilter
{
    //mude para true e observe o Output
    public bool AllowMultiple => false;

    private string name;

    public MyFilter(string nome)
    {
        name = nome;
    }

    public MyFilter()
    {

    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Passando pelo MyFilter {name}");
        var r = await  continuation.Invoke();
        return r;


    }
}
```

Na classe WebApiConfig.cs add as seguintes linhas:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Filters.Add(new MyFilter("Filtro A"));
        config.Filters.Add(new MyFilter("Filtro B"));

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Agora fazendo o teste com o AllowMultiple setado em true: O resultado foi:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao setar o AlloMultiple para false:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom, podemos concluir que toda vez que eu precisar realizar alguma ação nesses filtros onde devo ter obrigatoriamente dois eventos distintos por qualquer motivo que seja eu posso ir lá e add mais de uma instância para o meu filtro. Caso contrário eu seto AllowMultiple como false e somente o último adicionado na classe WebApiConfig será utilizado pois a ordem em que você adiciona importa.

Espero ter te ajudado.

Comment: Perfeito. Conceito e uso assimilado. Muitíssimo obrigado, mestre!